# Remove a Child in Firebase Database using FirebaseUI

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

FirebaseUI keeps track of changes in the DB and synchronises it with my TableView, which is good. I need the user to be able to remove childs by himself when swiping a tableView cell.

I'm using populateCellWithBlock to fill my table. However, I couldn't find anything about how to delete a child.
What I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource.init(query: getQuery(),prototypeReuseIdentifier: "Cellident", view: self.tableView)

    dataSource?.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
        //Filling the table:

        let customCell = cell as! CustomCellTableViewCell

        let snap = obj as! FIRDataSnapshot
        let childString = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]
        let data = childString["data"] as? String

        customCell.urlLabel.text = String(data!)

    }
    tableView.dataSource = dataSource
    tableView.delegate = self
}
```

Now, I've tried several approaches with Arrays, but couldn't figure out how to keep them synced. My problem is I can't figure out how to delete a child at a specific path, meaning the child which is in a single cell. How do I make sure the cell which is *swiped-to-delete* triggers the removal of the child from that cell?

My question is what the best practice here is, if I want the user to be able to remove a child. Obviously it needs to be removed from the database and from the tableView, but since FirebaseUI keeps track of changes, I'm sure there must be a way using FirebaseUI to delete it?

Comment: With FirebaseUI (and with the Firebase Database in general) it is recommended that you update the data in the database and let the UI updated based on that. This leads to a very unidirectional data flow, which (in my opinion) is often easiest to maintain.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks Frank, I thought so as well. But is there an actual code example? As mentioned, I'm struggling with how to delete specific Childs (the ones from the tableview above). With local data you would go with something like indexPath, but how can you do it here?

Comment: I'd expect [`datasource.objectAtIndex()`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/b619344646f7faf72f524b93f482d3303a300a29/FirebaseUI/Database/API/FirebaseDataSource.h#L53) to do the trick. `datasource.objectAtIndex(indexPath).ref.removeValue()`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks, I think that leads into the correct direction. However, what do I use for indexPath? It gives me the error of it being undefined. That is my difficulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying around, I found a solution. I'm using MGSwipeTableCell in order to make the cells swipeable and show a delete button, then inside it's convenience callback, I simply did:

```
let removebtn = MGSwipeButton(title: "Delete", backgroundColor: UIColor.redColor(), callback: {
            (sender: MGSwipeTableCell!) -> Bool in

            snap.ref.removeValue() //This

            return true
        })
```

Where snap is:

```
let snap = obj as! FIRDataSnapshot
```